# My inputs do not show up when I run my program. Why?

Tags: python

How can I fix the inputs? Because they do not show up when I run my program.

```
## Define the main module
def main():

    ## Initialize local Variables / Set Constant
    homeValue = 0
    propertyTaxRate = 0
    bedrooms = 0
    BEDROOMSURCHARGERATE = 0.0025

    ## Set initialized varialbes to user inputs
    homeValue = float(input("How much is your home worth?"))
    propertyTaxRate = float(input("What is your Property Tax Rate entered as a decimal?"))
    bedrooms = int(input("How many bedrooms will your house have?"))

    ## Set Variables equal to results of module outputs
    propertyTax = getPropertyTax(homeValue, propertyTaxRate)
    bedroomSurcharge = getBedroomSurcharge(BEDROOMSURCHARGERATE, bedrooms, homeValue)
    totalPropertyTax = getTotalPropertyTax(propertyTax, bedroomSurcharge)

    ## Report All information with a propertyTaxReport
    propertyTaxReport(homeValue, propertyTaxRate, bedrooms, propertyTax, bedroomSurcharge, totalPropertyTax)

## Define getPropertyTax Module
def getPropertyTax(homeValue, propertyTaxRate):

    ## Calculate property tax
    propertyTax = homeValue*propertyTaxRate

    return propertyTax

## Define getBedroomSurcharge
def getBedroomSurcharge(BEDROOMSURCHARGERATE, bedrooms, homeValue):

    ## Calculate Bedroom Surcharge
    bedroomSurcharge = BEDROOMSURCHARGERATE*bedrooms*homeValue

    return bedroomSurcharge

## Define getTotalPropertyTax
def getTotalPropertyTax(propertyTax, bedroomSurcharge):

    ## Calculate totalProperty Tax
    totalPropertyTax = propertyTax + bedroomSurcharge

    return totalPropertyTax

## Define propertyTaxReport
def propertyTaxReport(homeValue, propertyTaxRate, bedrooms, propertyTax, bedroomSurcharge, totalPropertyTax):

    ## Output Variables
    print("Your home costs ", homeValue, " dollars.")
    print("Your property tax rate is ", propertyTaxRate)
    print("Your house has ", bedrooms, "bedrooms")
    print("Your property tax is equal to ", propertyTax, " dollars.")
    print("Your bedroom surcharge is equal to ", bedroomSurchage, " dollars")
    print("Your total property tax comes out to ", totalPropertyTax, " dollars")
    return
```

Comment: please describe desired result / how you invoke the module. If you run by `python module.py` then in the module you should have line `if __name__=='__main__':` and below you should call the program entry point - `main()` I guess.

Comment: You don't need to initialize variables in python: all the first part `homeValue = 0; propertyTaxRate = 0...` can be avoided.

Comment: Is each of these definitions in a different module?? Please, show the structure of your program (in terms of files) and the imports.

Comment: `propertyTaxReport` has an empty `return`. Surely you don't need that.

Comment: In `propertyTaxReport`, one of the print statements calls `bedroomSurchage`, which should instead be `bedroomSurcharge`. Otherwise, your program works perfectly... but you never call the `main()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are drying a bit with your code.
A few suggestions:

1. You do not need to initialise a variable if this is an input from the user.
2. If you can simplify a calculation, just do it. Do not create many functions if they are not necessary.
3. You do not to print as output variables that the user gives as input. I guess the user already knows that. But if it is a serious report, maybe I can give you that.

Try this and let me know:

```
def main_function():
    BEDROOMSURCHARGERATE = 0.0025

    ## Set initialized variables to user inputs
    homeValue = float(input("How much is your home worth?"))
    propertyTaxRate = float(input("What is your Property Tax Rate entered as a decimal?"))
    bedrooms = int(input("How many bedrooms will your house have?"))

    ## Set Variables equal to results of module outputs
    propertyTax = homeValue*propertyTaxRate
    bedroomSurcharge = BEDROOMSURCHARGERATE*bedrooms*homeValue
    totalPropertyTax = propertyTax + bedroomSurcharge

    ## Report all information with a propertyTaxReport
    return (totalPropertyTax, f"bedroom Surcharge was {bedroomSurcharge}")
```

To call the function just do:

```
main_function()
```

You can return this tuple or print the whole thing you have at the end, up to you. I just point out that you can return just a value or a sentence.

Comment: If you mean [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) then the problem is that the OP is _not_ "drying".